# enumerate keys in in a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, dictionary

At debug time I would like to see what are the keys in my InitParams collection - I can't seem to be able to list them.

[image: InitParam]

EDIT:

As Jon suggests below, this might be a bug within the Silverlight debugger. To reproduce, just create a new Silverlight Application within Visual Studio 2010 
[image: bug silverlight] and just edit code

```
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"A", "1"}, {"B", "2"}, {"C", "3"}};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you only want the keys, use the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx) property:

```
foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to just get all the keys in an easy-to-read manner in the immediate window, you could use:

```
string.Join(";", dict.Keys)
```

or pre-.NET 4:

```
string.Join(";", dict.Keys.ToArray())
```

... or if you're using .NET 2, something like this:

```
string.Join(";", new List<string>(dict.Keys).ToArray())
```

If you want to get the values at the same time, you can iterate over the `KeyValuePair` entries as per Yaakov's answer.

EDIT: I would have *expected* Visual Studio to show you a nice representation of your dictionary by default, to be honest. For example, this is what I see in VS2008:

[image: dictionary in Visual Studio]

... and I've just tried it in VS2010 and seen the same result. Under the Debugging general options, have you got "Show raw structure of objects in variable windows" ticked? If so, untick it.

Comment: so I have to recompile my app? there is no way I can randomly check the content of my collection in the debugger, or immediate window or somewhere else I can't think of?

Comment: @bmanu: No, you don't have to recompile your app. That `string.Join` expression works in the Watch window. I'm surprised you're not seeing the dictionary in a nice form in Visual Studio already though... which version of VS are you using?

Comment: VisualStudio 2010. were you looking for a more precise answer? thanks for your help!

Comment: e.InitParams.Keys.ToArray()
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @bmanu: I was assuming you were already using LINQ. Which version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize this was within my silverlight application! so Silverlight 4 on Asp.net 4

Comment: @Jon: just checked,  'Show raw structure of objects in variable windows' is unticked

Comment: @bmanu: Okay... maybe it's a Silverlight debugging issue then. Could you give a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, so we can try to see it for ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Programatically:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> param in InitParams) {
  Debug.Writeline(param.Key + ": " + param.Value);
}
```

In the debugger, drilldown into InitParams > Values > Non-Public members > dictionary. It should show up eventually.

In the Immediate window, try something like `InitParams["abc"]` to show the value of the first item, where "abc" is a known Key in the collection. If you don't know the names of the Keys in the collection, then use the programmatic method above to write all of the values to the Debug window.

Comment: I would like to do this in the debugger actually. Immediate window would be ideal

Comment: e.InitParams[0] Return this:
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>.this[string]' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work as InitParams[] expects a string (which would need to correspond to one of the Keys in the collection). See corrected text above.

Comment: I agree, I could do this. I was really hoping not to recompile though. Thanks!